# Node.js - jquery code ignores the input required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

The jquery function runs ignoring the "required" attribute added to the input. Only after completing the POST request the "required" warning pops up.

index.handlebars

```
<form method="POST">
     <label for="burgerName">Nome do Burger:</label>
     <br>
     <input type="text" name="burgerName" placeholder="Nome do Burger" class="form-control">

     <button type="submit" id="add" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Adicionar Burger</button>
</form>
```

app.js

```
$("input[name='burgerName']").attr("required",true)

$("button[id='add']").on("click", (event) => {
    $("button[id='add']").attr("disabled","disabled")

    const burgerName = $("input[name='burgerName']").val()
    const burger = {
        bName: burgerName
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"/burgers/add",
        method: "POST",
        data: burger
    }).then((burger) => {
        addBurgerSuccess(burger)
    }).catch((erro) => {
        addBurgerFails(erro)
    })

    $("button[id='add']").removeAttr("disabled")
})
```

I need the "required" preventing empty data reaching the server, so , in order to achieve that, I need this restriction be activated before the request being made.

Thank you in advance.

1. [The server accepts an empty input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25s4Z.png)
2. [Only after closing the success message the warnings are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bIaB.png)

Comment: put the whole ajax into an if statement. if (burger != null) or something similar

Comment: I wish I could correctly display the styled "required" warning as well

Comment: I added the answer for your question on this comment

Comment: Trilogy coding bootcamp homework? :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is for your question in comment.

Here I added the border to the input (replace someclass with the class of your input or if its id #someid).

```
$("button[id='add']").on("click", (event) => {
    $("button[id='add']").attr("disabled","disabled")

    const burgerName = $("input[name='burgerName']").val();
    if (burgerName == ""){
    $(".someclass").css("border","1px solid red");
    }
    else {
    $(".someclass").css("border","1px solid green");
    }
    const burger = {
        bName: burgerName
    }
```

You can also addclass or removeclass as well and give that specific class red or green or any style.

```
$(".someclass").addClass("warning");
```

or

```
$(".someclass").removeClass("warning");
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but it keeps the same. After clicking on the add button is makes the PUT request and then runs an alert messge which is inside the addBurgerSuccess(burger) function. Only after closing the alert my "required" alert is shown up and now your css too. I would rather keep the "required" default warning since it is a pattern I'm using. Thank you.

Comment: I understand but when you need to prevent your program from posting when nothing is in the input. how do you wanna reach to the addburgersuccess or fail function and see the css?

Comment: You are right, I just needed a simple condition like X != "". That didn't make any sense to me since I had alread defined the input as "required". I thought it would be enough for jquery respect that. Thank you.